# What laws, if any, prevent a private individual from overthrowing or helping to overthrow another country´s government?

Tags: war

Could be personally participating in the overthrow, financing it, sending them weapons otherwise purchased and shipped legally, giving them intelligence, cracking into their computer networks to shut down their telecommunications, etc.

That would be illegal in the target country of course. But is it illegal anywhere else? And does it matter if they say had a bunch of UN bodies declaring them to be basically outlaws by violating the UN Charter?

Answer (score 3):

[18 USC 960](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/960) states that

> Whoever, within the United States, knowingly begins or sets on foot or
> provides or prepares a means for or furnishes the money for, or takes
> part in, any military or naval expedition or enterprise to be carried
> on from thence against the territory or dominion of any foreign prince
> or state, or of any colony, district, or people with whom the United
> States is at peace, shall be fined under this title or imprisoned not
> more than three years, or both.

"At peace" is not defined, but we can assume that a nation that the US is at war with would be exempt from this provision, then again it depends on what it means to be "at war" with a nation.

Comment: Given that the example I had in mind was Russia, that would be an interesting legal argument. The US is obviously helping Ukraine with a tremendous amount of war material and resources, and Russia has also basically been declared outlaws in many ways by the US, and by the ICJ and the UN General Assembly as well. It´s in a strange limbo land.

Comment: @R-Obsessive States are souvreign, and it is super hard to sue states, especially in courts of a different country.

Answer (score 1):

- [Extraterritorial Jurisdiction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extraterritorial_jurisdiction)
  Many countries claim the right to try crimes **by or against** their citizens, no matter where they happen. A coup attempt might include acts which are generally seen as ordinary crimes.
- [Terror Funding and Support](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terrorist_Financing_Convention)
  The term 'terrorist' has been twisted into a pretzel in recent decades, but many nations have signed up to relevant conventions. The coup attempt might possibly meet the definition of terrorism (use of force, political motive, intimidation of the population).

Answer (score 0):

You could run afoul of the law if your assistance consists of exporting munitions listed here:  [Munitions List](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-22/chapter-I/subchapter-M/part-121/subject-group-ECFRf7e5fe639be4566/section-121.1)